# Right way to recite Surah Fatiha

Tags: quran-recitation, surat-al-fatihah

I want to know what is the right way to recite the last verse of `Surah Fatiha`,

is it `Walaz Zauleen`.

or `Walad Dauleen`.

what is the right sound one should make i have consulted many Molvi in this regard some say first method is correct and some say the second is correct i tried searching it here but didnt seem to find a relevant question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part of the verse which you are reffering to

**الضَّالِّين**

I have never heard of the first one. I am from a country where alot people wrongfully pronounce the TH sound from ذ as a Z like sound but this is not TH sound it is a Tha ظـ which makes the D/TH sound. 
The Z sound is from letter zay ز. Listen to it in audio http://quran.com/1 and listen out for how the reciter pronounces it and look up various transliterations online. Basic tajweed is in order for this, so I recommend going to a quran class.

Comment: i have taken several Quran classes and thats where i was conflicted a few of preachers said to use the first one and few said use the second one.

Comment: @anas the correct one is the second one, some old people pronounce the letter 'ض' in arabic as z but it is wrong.

Comment: @user689 can you provide any reference also? jazak allah

Comment: I must agree with User689 and Jam its "walad dauleen" sounds like "walad Dthaaleen" the D/TH sound comes from the tounge against the inside of your cheek, I struggled with this sound, but my Ustaad form my darooloom helped me till I go it right .

Comment: @anas http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IPDCCdFR_dI

Comment: It's a "ض " not a "ظ" and there's also a big difference: the ض is a very powerfully emphasized and kind of prolonged pronounced "D" while "ظ" has something of a prolonged TH